# How to make one view bigger than the other views in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have few images in the json API, and I managed to fetch those images using volley Library. I used recyclerview with an image adapter to display image views vertically in two columns, but I want to make one image big and display it as the first image that user can click on. Also that image will be changed each interval of time. Basically, the API will do all the backend task like setting the time and telling which image to be displayed on the top of the recyclerview if not all images must have the same size and be shown in 2 columns vertically.

I have square layout class for recyclerview. I just want to know how I can do this. Even the concept will be fine.

[image: example]

Comment: You can use [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) instead of RecyclerView for easier implementation.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky can you please recommend me nice and effective source that i can learn flexbox for android.. thanks for your respond

Comment: also will you please tell me how i can implement wht i want without using flexboxLayout, so that i can say which is easy

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create two view one for small item other for the header item and in `onBindViewHolder` have to bind those accordingly the following code is an example of a news article app and should help.

```
public class AdapterNewsArticlesListWithHeader extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NewsArticles> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context ctx;
    private NewsArticles header;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, NewsArticles obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public AdapterNewsArticlesListWithHeader(Context context, NewsArticles header, List<NewsArticles> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.header = header;
    ctx = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView title;
    public TextView short_content;
    public TextView date;
    public ImageView image;
    public LinearLayout lyt_parent;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        short_content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.short_content);
        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        lyt_parent = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
    }
    }

    class ViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView date;
    public ImageView image;
    public LinearLayout lyt_parent;

    public ViewHolderHeader(View v) {
        super(v);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        lyt_parent = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_header, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderHeader(v);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_news, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    return null;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderHeader) {
        ViewHolderHeader vHeader = (ViewHolderHeader) holder;
        vHeader.title.setText(header.getTitle());
        vHeader.date.setText(header.getDate());
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(header.getImage()).into(vHeader.image);
        vHeader.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO: do your thing
            }
        });

    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        final NewsArticles c = items.get(position);
        ViewHolder vItem = (ViewHolder) holder;
        vItem.title.setText(c.getTitle());
        vItem.short_content.setText(c.getShort_content());
        vItem.date.setText(c.getDate());
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(c.getImage()).into(vItem.image);
        vItem.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO: do your thing
            }
        });
    }

    }

    //    need to override this method
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
    }

    public NewsArticles getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share all xml code and layout manager to be set on recycler veiw?